# Delete everything before a double quote

Tags: regex, bash, openrefine, grel

I'm trying to clean a CSV file which has a column with contents like this:

```
Sometexthere1", "code"=>"47.51-2-01"}]
```

And I would like to remove everything before the first quote (") in order to keep just this:

```
Sometexthere1
```

I know that I can use $` to get everything before some match in regex, but I am not understanding how to keep just the string before the first double quote.

Comment: is the given sample part of line or the entire line? also add the code/command you tried to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean "delete everything **after** a double quote"? In Open Refine, you can use this GREL formula :

```
value.replace(/".+/, "")


> Result : Sometexthere1
```

Answer (score 2):

[Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) does this well enough:

```
# Define a variable
s='Sometexthere1", "code"=>"47.51-2-01"}]'

# expand it, removing the longest possible match (from the end) for '"'*
result=${s%%'"'*}

# demonstrate that result by printing it
printf '%s\n' "$result"
```

...properly returns `Sometexthere1`.

Comment: Both *substring removal* and *substring replacement* will fit the bill. e.g `result="${s//\"*/}"` as well.